# Intermediate Value Theorem without an interval?

Tags: derivatives

Final Soon. I'm pretty sure the Professor said there would be an intermediate value theorem question asking to prove a function has a zero without a given interval.

I tried thinking of how this can be done but we never did that and I cant think of a way to do it. I thought maybe critical points and test points around it but I dont think that would work.

Comment: "Without an interval" ? What does this mean? Outside of the interval? Or do you mean that it has a zero inside the interval?

Comment: The question is vague. I would guess that you will be given enough information to determine that the function has negative & positive values from which you can made the desired conclusion.

Comment: @MPW I described it in the 3 sentences following... A function is given, only the function. No interval is provided. And are asked to prove that the function given has a zero

Comment: There is no general way, you may use limits at infinity if they happen to be of opposite sign, but that's not a necessary condition. And to use that you would need for the function to be continuous on all $\Bbb R$. If it doesn't work you need to pick values at random and test them. For a given function there might be tricks but it's impossible to list.

Comment: Make sure to upvote and accept an answer (by clicking on the checkmark by it) if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of how that might go:

- **Problem**: Show that the function $f(x)=x^{17}-48x^5+x^2-3$ has a zero. *Note that I have no clue how to actually find a zero for this function*.
- **Solution**: Plugging in $x=1$ gives a negative value (namely, $-49$) while plugging in $x=-1$ gives a positive value (namely, $45$). By the intermediate value theorem, somewhere on the interval $[-1,1]$ we have $f(x)=0$.

Note that *we've found the interval ourselves*. So part of the problem, in fact, is producing that bit of information.

---

We can even solve problems of this type without finding any specific interval at all. One basic, and quite useful, theorem about polynomials is the following:

> Suppose $p$ is an odd-degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient (e.g., $17x^5-12435235x^2+3$). Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow-\infty}p(x)=-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}p(x)=\infty$.

This immediately tells us that *any odd degree polynomial with positive leading coefficient has a zero*: by the theorem, we can find $a$ and $b$ with $p(a)<0$ and $p(b)>0$ (pick $a$ "really small" and $b$ "really big"), and so by the intermediate value theorem $p$ has a zero between $a$ and $b$; *and this argument works even though we have no idea what good examples of $a$ and $b$ might be!*

(And note that the positivity of the leading coefficient matters for the values of the limits at infinity, but not for the existence of a zero: if the leading coefficient of $p$ is negative, think about $-p$.)

---

Basically, you're being asked to be a bit creative with the intermediate value theorem: given a function, think about what you know about the function (or can find out about it) and see if you can notice some facts which will let you set up a situation where you can use the intermediate value theorem. In this case there's not much variety: you'll always be looking for one point where it's negative and one point where it's positive, or at least for an argument that such points need to exist even if you can't find them exactly. But in more general situations, applying a given theorem isn't always easy. Indeed, it's often not even clear that a given theorem is even relevant!

Comment: Thanks I think I kind of figured it out and your comment pretty much went along the logic I was thinking. Initially I thought doing the limits at +/- infinity. If we know that the limits at infinity are the same sign then we dont know if theres a zero but its still possible for one somewhere in between. Using the derivative we find the critical points and use those critical points as boundaries for intervals to be used for testing using the IVT. If there is a zero then one of those intervals should show it.